# What is the type (or package) of this IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit

Recently I found such IC on a PCB. I have never seen such package and wonder what it could be? Please, help me identify the type of this package. (It seems like an IC adapter, but has the same pins pitch inside and outside, so probably it is not an IC adapter).

The yellow things is just dirty PCB, it doesn`t matter.

[image]

Comment: You could have cleaned off the dirt a bit before taking the picture.

Comment: Unfortunately it is strong glue and couldn`t be cleaned up easily.

Answer (score 14):

This isn't an IC. This is a miniature board-to-board connector. We find them a lot in mobile phones, either to connect two boards together, or to connect the screen, the camera, ... We can also find them in pocket cameras, tablets, basically anything tiny.

Some examples from [Hirose](https://www.hirose.com/product/en/products/DF23/), [JAE](http://www.jae.com/jccom/en/connectors/detail/WP3), [Molex](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=slimstack_fine_pitch_smt_board_to_board_connectors&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=board_to_board_connectors), ... Every manufacturer offers some, but there is no universal standard for them.

Comment: Thank you! After you said it is a connector, I actually have remembered that I saw similar "things" earlier, but bigger and with more pins. This one is quite small and looks like IC, so that`s why it confused me.